Makefile trying to capture docker image id but getting empty string
build-and-push:
    IMAGE_ID=$(docker image ls | awk '$1 ~ /^apache\/spark-py/ {print $3}')
    echo "${IMAGE_ID}"

I'm trying to capture the docker image_id in a makefile. If I run
docker image ls | awk '$1 ~ /^apache\/spark-py/ {print $3}
at the command line, I get the image ID just fine, however in a makefile, it returns nothing. I tried cutting it down to just IMAGE_ID=$(docker image ls') and that returns nothing too.
What kinds of fix should be made here to make this work?

This is a very common make FAQ. Each command in a recipe runs in a separate subshell. The duplicate has multiple solutions; what's best depends on what you want to accomplish. This simple example is mainly just a useless use of echo

That's not the only bug in this makefile.  You also have to escape the $ that you want to pass to the shell, using $$
